# Pass a directory into a variable in Python

Tags: python, tar

I am trying to modify a script off of GitHub that will access a TAR file and process it. There is a variable in the code that needs to point to the root directory where the file is housed (I think...). Below is the code:

```
def make_Dictionary(root_dir):
    emails_dirs = [os.path.join(root_dir,f) for f in os.listdir(root_dir)]    
    all_words = []       
    for emails_dir in emails_dirs:
        emails = [os.path.join(emails_dir,f) for f in os.listdir(emails_dir)]
        for mail in emails:
            with open(mail) as m:
                 for line in m:
                     words = line.split()
                     all_words += words
    dictionary = Counter(all_words)
    list_to_remove = dictionary.keys()

    for item in list_to_remove:
        if item.isalpha() == False: 
            del dictionary[item]
        elif len(item) == 1:
             del dictionary[item]
    dictionary = dictionary.most_common(4000)

    np.save('dict_movie.npy',dictionary) 

    return dictionary

root_dir = sys.path[0]
dictionary = make_Dictionary(root_dir)
```

root_dir is throwing:

```
  File "C:\Users\seand\eclipse-workspace\sentiment_project\src\root\nested\movie-polarity.py", line 22, in make_Dictionary
    emails = [os.path.join(emails_dir,f) for f in os.listdir(emails_dir)]
NotADirectoryError: [WinError 267] The directory name is invalid: 'C:\\Users\\seand\\eclipse-workspace\\sentiment_project\\src\\root\\nested\\movie-polarity-tfidf.py'
```

The directions state "Note : Directory path of corpus in movie-polarity-tfidf.py and movie-polarity.py needs to be set accordingly." but the path I am specifying contains the corpus TAR file the script needs. I don't understand why, if the script is looking for a directory, this .py file is getting picked up.

Comment: What is the value held in `sys.path[0]`?  Normally, `sys.path[0]` will be the user's current directory.

Comment: @StephenRauch Indeed it is. Fixed!

Comment: @KindStranger If I print the root_dir variable I get: C:\Users\seand\eclipse-workspace\sentiment_project\src\root\nested However when it's passed into the mark_Dictionary function it seems to be grabbing a file at the end and telling me the directory is invalid.

Comment: So `emails_dirs` should contain only directories presumably?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`os.listdir` lists everything in the directory.  This includes both files and directories.  I assume you want only directories the first time (to generate list of `email_dirs`) and only files the second time (to generate list of `emails`).

```
def make_Dictionary(root_dir):
    # # # Check for only directories # # #
    emails_dirs = [os.path.join(root_dir,f) for f in os.listdir(root_dir) if os.path.isdir(f)]    
    all_words = []       
    for emails_dir in emails_dirs:
        # # # Check for only files # # #
        emails = [os.path.join(emails_dir,f) for f in os.listdir(emails_dir) if os.path.isfile(f)]
        for mail in emails:
            with open(mail) as m:
                 for line in m:
                     words = line.split()
                     all_words += words
    dictionary = Counter(all_words)
    list_to_remove = dictionary.keys()

    for item in list_to_remove:
        if item.isalpha() == False: 
            del dictionary[item]
        elif len(item) == 1:
             del dictionary[item]
    dictionary = dictionary.most_common(4000)

    np.save('dict_movie.npy',dictionary) 

    return dictionary

root_dir = sys.path[0]
dictionary = make_Dictionary(root_dir)
```

Comment: Thanks @Kind Stranger and everyone else for your help. Your suggestions did solve that error but now the for item in list_to_remove loop is throwing an error. I don't want to ask you guys to debug this entire script.  This is not my code. It is from https://github.com/abhijeet3922/Sentiment-Analysis-using-tf-idf---Polarity-dataset

Comment: @Sean, noproblem!  Just add debug lines **everywhere** to see exactly what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

The comprehension for `emails_dirs` is returning some non-directories.  Likely can be fixed with:

```
emails_dirs = [os.path.join(root_dir,f) for f in os.listdir(root_dir)
               if os.path.isdir(os.path.join(root_dir,f))]
```

Answer (score 0):

you are using `os.path.join(rootdir,f)` in first line of the function, so email_dirs is a list of absolute paths, but not directories. so you got the exception.